# Prevent Ajax CSS to ruin main CSS with JQuery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax

I'm working on a web page that calls another page with great jquery ajax abilities. My problem is : there is a css file in ajax page. The page which is called needs it but I don't want to see sub page's css styles in my main page.

Here is a summary of how I call my sub page :

```
<script>
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
    url: "subpage.html",
    success: function(msg){
       $('#box').html(msg);
    }
});
</script>

<div id='box'>
</div>
```

So, subpage.html is a kind of interface to another module of my project and it has its OWN CSS FILES. Any great knowledge or tricks to prevent that css file from my main page? PHP solutions are also acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `iframe`s ([W3C reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp), [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/iframe)). To load a specific page in an `iframe` using JavaScript, use something like this, HTML:

```
<iframe id = "iframeID" height = "300px" width = "300px"></iframe>
```

Then, when you want to load the page:

```
document.getElementById("iframeID").src = "subpage.html";
```

Comment: well, I don't know why but people don't like using iframe when there is ajax and I think that's why I see a negative mark on this post. Anyway, I accept this solution thankfully.

Comment: it'll be helpful to the community at large if your title had been a tad more indicative of what you were looking for; seems to me that you're looking for a solution while retaining the ajax load, but the answer you've accepted looks like it pretty much would replace the ajax load entirely. perhaps your title should be somewhere along the lines of "another way apart from ajax to load in subpage to main document".. just my 2 cents' worth =)

Comment: actually I wasn't originally searching for a replacement but with a few  jquery.contents() trick I was able to handle the problem and if there is another way to do that with ajax, I would appreciate it and accept that answer while unaccepting this one. That's why I'll check this page for a week at least. =)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this, you can use jQuery.load like so:

```
$('#box').load('subpage.html #the_id_of_something');
```

This example will load the content of `#the_id_of_something` from `subpage.html` into `#box` on your page.

Comment: Quite sure that's not what the OP wanted.

Comment: The point is that he wants to load various elements from `subpage.html`, but without the CSS defined inside `subpage.html` affecting the rest of the page.

Comment: Can't he just use `html` as the selector, then he wouldn't get the CSS defined in its `head`?

Comment: well, that's right, I've already handled the calling issue. And my sub page needs its css, so I can't just deny it.